# Toggle next element (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, click, toggle, slide

HTML:

```
<div class="interview">
    <h4>Interview</h4>
    <a href="#" class="question">This is question 1?</a>
    <div class="answer">This is an answer!</div>
    <a href="#" class="question">This is question 2?</a>
    <div class="answer">This is an answer!</div>
    <a href="#" class="question">This is question 3?</a>
    <div class="answer">This is an answer!</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
if ($('interview')[0]) {
    $('interview .question').toggle(function () {
        $(this).next('.answer').slideIn();
    },
    function () {
        $(this).next('.answer').slideOut();
    });
}
```

... I can't figure out why it isn't working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mind the dot:

```
.interview
```

Also, there is no *slideIn*, try `slideDown` and `slideUp`: http://jsbin.com/ajawo3

If you don't have any other code in these functions, a better choice is `slideToggle`: http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Answer (score 1):

You are using a class selector and it should begin with a `.`

So you have to change

```
$('interview .question')
```

to

```
$('div.interview .question')
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres a simple version...

```
$('a.question').click(function () {     
    $(this).next('.answer').slideToggle();
});
```